# Git - download production repo to local repo

Tags: git

I have installed production Airflow worklow management on VPS. Now I need to download production repo to local repo for development, then push it back to origin production repo. Global user in both repos is same (not sure if it plays role..)

Steps I made:

In production server repo:

1. git init in  /home/user/airflow/
2. git add .
3. git commit

Should I also make hook post-receive file?

In local repo:

4. git init in my local folder
5. git remote add origin user@101.101.101.101:.git (am I using right syntax here?)
6. git pull origin master

Please advise what Im doing wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Try cloning the repo `git clone user@101.101.101.101:.git`

Comment: `git init` you are doing only once when starting new project. All others are doing `git clone` to create copy of existing repository. Then you use `git push` to send your changes to other repo and `git pull`/`git fetch` to receive changes from other repo. Please read some git tutorial again, since all this are a basics of git.

Comment: And for now forget about git hooks. This is for git experts only (at least for advanced very users). Default one are good for you. Cases where you should alter them are rare.

Comment: Thank  you!

1. So I cloned production repo to my local machineadded some files